# Is a normal line to a constant function defined?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

This is probably more so an attempt to clarify definitions rather than prove anything, but my question is roughly as follows: in $2D$ space, the naive way to define a normal line to some function $f(x)$ at a given point is through *perpendicularity* to the tangent line at that point. Algebraically, this is expressed as the negative reciprocal of the slope of the tangent line. But since the slope of a constant function is always $0$, such a reciprocal is clearly undefined. Now, mathematically that makes sense because this normal line wouldn't be a function, but *graphically* it doesn't, as it's really easy to draw a line perpendicular to a constant function at any given point. So, my first question is whether there exists a way to deal with such an object in a formal manner? And secondly, does the normal even *have to* be a function in the rigorous sense? I'm not well-versed in formal geometry, so I'm not sure what alternative definitions exist that could bridge this gap between mathematical definitions and graphical intuition.

Comment: If you want to be formal about it, you can treat it as a relation from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. But you are right that it won't be a function and so cannot necessarily use properties of functions to deal with the new object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A normal is a straight line and a straight line needn't be described by a function.

$$x=x_0$$ is the equation of a vertical line.

---

By the way, a curve needn't be described by a function either.

$$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$$ is the equation of a circle.